# Deriving Power Spectral Density of $a \cdot x(t)+b$ if PSD of $x(t)$ is known

Tags: power-spectral-density

I want to derive the PSD of $a \cdot x(t)+b$ if the PSD of $x(t)$ is known. Here $a$ and $b$ are constant. The signal $x(t)$ is a zero mean stationary random variable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**[Disclaimer]**
*This was a homework question I answered fully a while ago and then deleted, but I'm un-deleting because the OP hasn't re-appeared.*

For a WSS random process $x(t)$, the Power Spectral Density is defined as the Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation $R_x(\tau)$:

$$S_x(f) = \mathscr{F}(R_x(\tau))$$
With the definition of $R_x(\tau)$,
$$R_x(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\big[x^*(t)x(t+\tau)\big]$$
We have:
\begin{align}
R_{ax+b}(\tau) &= \mathbb{E}\big[(ax^*(t)+b)\cdot(ax(t+\tau)+b)\big]\\\\
&=\mathbb{E}\big[(a^2x^*(t)x(t+\tau)\big]+ab\mathbb{E}\big[x^*(t)\big] + ab\mathbb{E}\big[x(t+\tau)\big]+\mathbb{E}\big[b^2\big]\\\\
&=a^2R_x(\tau) + 2ab\mu_x + b^2
\end{align}
Now take the Fourier Transform:
$$S_{ax+b}(f) = a^2S_x(f) + 2ab\mu_x\delta(f) + b^2\delta(f)$$
Since the signal is zero-mean, the second term vanishes, so you can simplify this to:
$$S_{ax+b}(f) = a^2S_x(f) + b^2\delta(f)$$

Comment: This was homework, I'm sure.  I wouldn't have necessarily spoon-fed this to the OP, but I don't think we want a mistake or omission it in.